# Einstein's equation: good, intuitive introduction anywhere?

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations

Baez - like most others - gives (IMHO) a quite unsatisfactory [introduction to Einstein's equation](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/einstein/node3.html). They all start with the equivalence principle or similarly unintuitive reasoning, relating it to special relativity and so on. But I did not find any introduction that gives me an intuitive description of what the Einstein equation actually describes.

Baez talks about $t$-momentum. What is a $t$-momentum? And what is a $t$-momentum in t-direction? And then what would a $t$-momentum in $x$-direction be? And what do I have to think of a $t$-momentum **flow**? He explains: "The flow of $t$-momentum in the $t$-direction is just the energy density." As if that explains anything at all.

IMHO a **much** better approach would be to describe simple experimental results and then show how to calculate them using Einstein's equation, maybe using a reduced and simplistic form initially.

Comment: It's easy to explain GR in a popular sense, but if you want to calculate with it (to relate to experimental results) you can't really expect a non-mathematical treatment. I think you need to rephrase your question to specify what level of description you are asking for. If you do have some mathematical background, there are a lot of good introductory GR textbooks and I really recommend getting one of those and work through the text if you want to learn it. An example is Schutz, A first course in general relativity.

Comment: The Schutz book is the way I learned GR, but not all members of this site are fans of Schutz's approach.